# $and with sub $and not yielding expected results in mongo with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
modelThreader.find({
        $and: [
            {"date_entered": { $lt: fromTime }},
            {"cancelled": { $ne: true }},
            {"hideFromUserIds.id": { $ne: current_user_id }},
            {"banned": false},
            {$and: [
                {"user_id": { $ne: current_user_id }},
                {"privacy": { $ne: 1 }}
            ]}
        ]
    }).exec(function( err, docs ){

   // handle response.

});
```

I am having troubles with a seemingly simple query in mongo.

The above query i need all of the first lot to be as set in the query ie:

```
{"date_entered": { $lt: fromTime }},
{"cancelled": { $ne: true }},
{"hideFromUserIds.id": { $ne: current_user_id }},
{"banned": false},
```

This works fine, as expected. However I need to add to this query as the doc schema has changed.

There is a new field "privacy" where int 1 is private and should only be returned to the user to everyone. As you can see from my query i am trying to say

```
{$and: [
   {"user_id": { $ne: current_user_id }},
   {"privacy": { $ne: 1 }}
]}
```

ie, if the current_user_id is the one requesting the query, don't apply any privacy filter, otherwise, only return docs with privacy is not 1.

The problem is that it is applying $ne:1 to all users including the current_user_id...

EDIT
The only way i can achieve the desired result is to do a giant $or but this feels inefficient:

where or is an array of other user_id's

```
$or: [
                        {$and: [
                            //other people, respecting privacy
                            {$or: or},
                            {"date_entered": { $lt: fromTime }},
                            {"cancelled": { $ne: true }},
                            {"hideFromUserIds.id": { $ne: current_user_id }},
                            {"banned": false},
                            {"user_id":         { $ne: current_user_id }},
                            {"privacy":     { $ne: 1 }}
                        ]},
                        {$and: [
                            //this user, not looking at privacy
                            {"date_entered": { $lt: fromTime }},
                            {"cancelled": { $ne: true }},
                            {"hideFromUserIds.id": { $ne: current_user_id }},
                            {"banned": false},
                            {"user_id": current_user_id }
                        ]}
                    ]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the obvious compound logic here, in which there is only a "small portion" that is the equivalent [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition:

```js
modelThreader.find({
  "date_entered": { "$lt": fromTime },
  "cancelled": { "$ne": true },
  "banned": false,
  "$or": [
    { "user_id": current_user_id },
    {
      "user_id": { "$ne": current_user_id },
      "hideFromUserIds.id": { "$ne": current_user_id },
      "privacy": { "$ne": 1 }            
  ]
})
```

Where the other "tweak" in the logic there is that `"hideFromUserIds.id"` will not matter to the `current_user_id` as the match to `"user_id"` since it's already them.

**ALL** MongoDB query conditions are *"already"* an "AND" condition unless explicitly stated otherwise. So anything sitting "outside" of the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) is considered an "AND" expression in addition to the arguments applied "within" the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) expression.

So the only things inside the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) are those conditions that would apply to *"other users"* in the breakdown of the logic. Otherwise everything else is applied as an "AND" in all cases.

In the end you are confusing the terms. Because when your results mean you want *"**either** of these conditions in **addition** to the other results"*, then you actually mean [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)